# LaTeX - two columns within the same listing?

Tags: latex, listings

I'm trying to achieve the following but with no problems in spacing.

The image is what I'm trying to achieve but without the spacing problems :

[image]

At the moment it's just a normal listing with tabbing.

I want to avoid tabbing by introducing two columns. Is that possible?

Current code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Elements of time in the background knowledge, label=btime]

year(Y):-                       hour(H):-
   Y in 2000..2011.                 H in 0..23.

month(M):-                  minute(M):-
   M in 1..12.                      M in 0..59.

day_of_month(D):-               seconds(S):-
    D in 1..31.                     minute(S).

date([D, M, Y]):-                   time([H,M]):-
    year(Y),                            hour(H),
    month(M),                       minute(M).
    day_of_month(D).                            

\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: I don't want to put one below the other since it wastes a lot of space and looks ugly!

Comment: What about just using the tabular environment (I might not understand what the listing environment is doing for you -- I've not used it)?

Comment: I've attempted that, but it doesn't give me the exact outcome (see link) that I want. Or I don't know how to achieve it

Comment: can someone migrate this to the latex stackexchange forum? there might be someone who can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (result looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prUwV.png))?

```
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
 year(Y):-                           &  hour(H):-      \\
  \hspace{10mm}Y in 2000..2011.      &   \hspace{10mm} H in 0..23.    \\
& \\
 month(M):-                          &  minute(M):-    \\
  \hspace{10mm} M in 1..12.          &   \hspace{10mm} M in 0..59.    \\
& \\
 day\_of\_month(D):-                 &  seconds(S):-   \\
  \hspace{10mm} D in 1..31.          &   \hspace{10mm} minute(S).     \\
& \\
 date([D, M, Y]):-                   &   \hspace{10mm} time([H,M]):-  \\
      \hspace{10mm} year(Y),         &   \hspace{15mm} hour(H),       \\
  \hspace{10mm} month(M),            &   \hspace{10mm} minute(M).     \\
  \hspace{10mm} day\_of\_month(D).   &                 \\
\end{tabular}
```

- Tweak the values `p{Xcm}` to get the column distance you want
- Tweak the values `\hspace{Xmm}` to get the indentation you want

  - An alternative would be to use `\quad` or `\qquad`, though that might not be enough for you